# npm install not installing things at /usr/bin

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sails.js, waterline, ubuntu-13.04

I am trying to install SailsJS with:

```
$ sudo npm install -g sails
```

It works, install everything at /home/brunoluiz/npm/lib/node_modules/sails with the following log:

```
/home/brunoluiz/npm/bin/sails -> /home/brunoluiz/npm/lib/node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js
sails@0.9.16 /home/brunoluiz/npm/lib/node_modules/sails
├── connect-flash@0.1.1
├── pluralize@0.0.5
├── inflection@1.2.5
├── grunt-sails-linker@0.9.5
├── grunt-contrib-clean@0.4.1
├── node-uuid@1.4.0
├── async@0.2.9
├── grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0
├── grunt-contrib-copy@0.4.1
├── grunt-contrib-coffee@0.7.0
├── ejs-locals@1.0.2
├── ejs@0.8.4
├── underscore.string@2.3.0
├── coffee-script@1.6.2
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── i18n@0.4.1 (debug@0.8.0, sprintf@0.1.3)
├── optimist@0.3.4 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
├── include-all@0.1.2 (underscore.string@2.3.1)
├── sails-disk@0.9.3 (waterline-criteria@0.9.7, lodash@2.3.0, fs-extra@0.8.1)
├── fs-extra@0.5.0 (jsonfile@0.0.1, ncp@0.2.7, mkdirp@0.3.5, rimraf@2.1.4)
├── connect-redis@1.4.5 (debug@0.8.0, redis@0.7.3)
├── grunt-contrib-jst@0.5.0 (lodash@1.0.1, grunt-lib-contrib@0.5.3)
├── glob@3.1.14 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.1.14, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.6.1 (grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1, clean-css@1.0.12)
├── grunt-cli@0.1.9 (resolve@0.3.1, nopt@1.0.10, findup-sync@0.1.3)
├── grunt-contrib-watch@0.4.4 (gaze@0.3.4, tiny-lr@0.0.4)
├── connect-mongo@0.3.2 (mongodb@1.2.14)
├── grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.2 (grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── waterline@0.9.16 (underscore@1.5.2, q@0.9.7, anchor@0.9.12)
├── grunt@0.4.1 (which@1.0.5, dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3, eventemitter2@0.4.13, colors@0.6.2, hooker@0.2.3, async@0.1.22, nopt@1.0.10, minimatch@0.2.14, lodash@0.9.2, rimraf@2.0.3, coffee-script@1.3.3, underscore.string@2.2.1, iconv-lite@0.2.11, glob@3.1.21, findup-sync@0.1.3, js-yaml@2.0.5)
├── winston@0.7.1 (cycle@1.0.3, stack-trace@0.0.9, eyes@0.1.8, colors@0.6.2, pkginfo@0.3.0, request@2.16.6)
├── express@3.4.0 (methods@0.0.1, debug@0.8.0, range-parser@0.0.4, cookie-signature@1.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.1.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, commander@1.2.0, send@0.1.4, connect@2.9.0)
├── grunt-contrib-less@0.9.0 (grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1, chalk@0.4.0, less@1.6.3)
└── socket.io@0.9.14 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.11)
```

The problem is when you try to use sails: you run `sails new project`, for example, and it doesn't find sails. Investigating a little bit, I discovered npm is not installing the modules at /usr/bin. Is there some reason for that? Some config?

The same is happening with Karma module.

I used the nodejs from ppa, created the symbolic link for node and installed npm from the official install.sh script (https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like your `npm` installation is configured to use `/home/brunoluiz/npm` as `prefix`, meaning that it will place symlinks to the CLIs that come with globally installed packages in `{prefix}/bin`.

In a default installation, `prefix` is either `/usr` or `/usr/local` on Unix platforms (`%APPDATA%/npm` on Windows).

If `{prefix}/bin` is not in your `$PATH`, you won't be able to execute such CLIs just by name.

To see the current `prefix` value in effect, run:

```
npm get prefix
```

Your options are:

- Add `/home/brunoluiz/npm/bin` to your `$PATH`
- Change the value of the `prefix` configuration item to a folder whose `bin` subfolder is already in your `$PATH`; e.g.:

```bsh
    npm set prefix /usr       # Ubuntu; CLI symlinks are placed in /usr/bin
    npm set prefix /usr/local # OSX; CLIs symlinks are placed in /usr/local/bin
```

Note, however, that you'd then have to reinstall your global packages for the symlinks to be created in the new `{prefix}\bin` location.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mklement0's answer, the first solution (adding the npm binary directory path to the PATH variable) creates another problem when the commands are run with `sudo` prefix on Linux environment. To solve it, the npm binary directory path must also be added in `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers.tmp`. Here is how:
[Why can't sudo find a command after I added it to PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611528/why-cant-sudo-find-a-command-after-i-added-it-to-path)