# npm seems not to be updated after updating

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I update npm, it is successfully finished. However, if I ask npm's version, it still gives the old version:

[image]

I also tried many other ways to update npm, for all of them it seems to be updated but if I run `npm -v` I still get the old version. Restarting machine, cleaning cache etc. does not help.

If I run npm, I also see that it is really the old version so it is somehow not updated.

---

npm is installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

and my Path:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/TeX/:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/builder/bin:.
```

Comment: What do you get when you execute `which npm`?

Comment: it is `/usr/bin/npm`

Comment: In that case, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23091158/612920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the `npm` command, or any other command, the shell is going to search in the `PATH` directories one by one. It will use the first path it encounters containing the command binary.

To find out which path is used, you can use the `which` command

```
which npm
```

which is probably going to be either `/bin` or `/usr/bin` (`/usr/bin/X11` being unlikely because it contains X11, the linux windowing system)

In order to use your updated npm version you can:

1. Add `/usr/local/bin` to the beginning of the `PATH`
2. Copy npm manually to `/usr/bin`, but that is probably not a good idea since you would need to do that for every npm update
3. Change npm `prefix` /usr/local

   npm set prefix /usr/local

Answer (score 0):

### **NPM** : (without NVM)

To upgrade npm to the latest version on Windows, you can use the following command in the Command Prompt or PowerShell:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

After running the command, npm will download and install the latest version. Once the installation is complete, you can verify the updated version by running:

```
npm --version
```

Hope this helps!
[image]